# Print Successfully Saved Code in Php

Tags: php

I am using below code, how do i do the message as saved successfully, after submitting all the values in database.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO applyonline (name, email, gender, phone, dob, applicationintake, applicationintake2, degree, ielts, experience, experience2) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."','".$gender."','".$phone."','".$dob."','".$applicationintake1."','".$applicationintake2."','".$degree."','".$ielts."','".$experience1."','".$experience2."')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First** you should read this thread: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)

Then, [reading the doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-query.php) you will see that `mysql_query` return true or false for INSERT query.

So:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO applyonline (name, email, gender, phone, dob, applicationintake, applicationintake2, degree, ielts, experience, experience2) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."','".$gender."','".$phone."','".$dob."','".$applicationintake1."','".$applicationintake2."','".$degree."','".$ielts."','".$experience1."','".$experience2."')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (true === $result)
{
  echo 'All right !';
}
else
{
  echo 'Something is wrong: ' . mysql_error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO applyonline (name, email, gender, phone, dob, applicationintake, applicationintake2, degree, ielts, experience, experience2) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."','".$gender."','".$phone."','".$dob."','".$applicationintake1."','".$applicationintake2."','".$degree."','".$ielts."','".$experience1."','".$experience2."')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('error while saving data');
if($result){
  echo 'data saved successfully';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the die to stop the script else display saved successfully.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO applyonline (name, email, gender, phone, dob, applicationintake, applicationintake2, degree, ielts, experience, experience2) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."','".$gender."','".$phone."','".$dob."','".$applicationintake1."','".$applicationintake2."','".$degree."','".$ielts."','".$experience1."','".$experience2."')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Could not save");
if ($result)
echo "<br>Saved</br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything within the if statement will be processed if the entry into the database is a success.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO applyonline (name, email, gender, phone, dob, applicationintake, applicationintake2, degree, ielts, experience, experience2) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."','".$gender."','".$phone."','".$dob."','".$applicationintake1."','".$applicationintake2."','".$degree."','".$ielts."','".$experience1."','".$experience2."')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result){
    echo "Data has been saved";
}
```

Comment: Apologies, missed previous answers.

Comment: Must say you beauty. Great @Thanks a lot @ :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO applyonline (name, email, gender, phone, dob, applicationintake, applicationintake2, degree, ielts, experience, experience2) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."','".$gender."','".$phone."','".$dob."','".$applicationintake1."','".$applicationintake2."','".$degree."','".$ielts."','".$experience1."','".$experience2."')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if($result){
  echo 'data saved successfully';
}

mysql_error() function will explain you error in detail .
```